# how to interpret this adjective alone, not linked to any noun?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english

I came across this headline:

> "Coming soon to this coal county: **solar**, in a big way"

is "solar" in this context a generalization? like referring to solar panels and everything that can be solar?

Comment: Here, "solar" refers to *solar power* only. For instance, "solar radiation" or "solar flares" aren't included

Answer (score 2):

Although "solar" is very often used as an adjective, here is is used as a noun, meaning (from the context) "solar power".

Omitting the word "power" is fairly common in this context.

> **Nuclear** is a zero-emission clean energy source.

> **Renewables**, including **solar**, **wind**, **hydro**, **biofuels** and others, are at the centre of the transition

All the emboldened words are used as nouns.